# Gtk#, CellRendererCombo, always show drop-down, disable typing?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

The code is below, and it currently looks like this:
[image]

1. It seems that the `CellRendererCombo` looks like a `CellRendererText`, and I have to double-click it to show the drop-down list. Is it possible to show drop-down button always, like this?

[image]

2. Currently, one can type into the combo box. Is it possible to restrict to choosing only from the existing values (male, female), not allowing typing new text?
   [image]

---

Source code

```
        st = new Gtk.TreeStore(typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(string));
        st.AppendValues("Homer", 38, "male");
        st.AppendValues("Marge", 34, "female");

        MyTree.Model = st;

        var r1 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        var r2 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        var r3 = new Gtk.CellRendererCombo();
        var genders = new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string));
        genders.AppendValues("male");
        genders.AppendValues("female");
        r3.Model = genders;
        r3.TextColumn = 0;
        r3.Editable = true;

        MyTree.Columns[0].PackStart(r1, false);
        MyTree.Columns[1].PackStart(r2, false);
        MyTree.Columns[2].PackStart(r3, false);

        MyTree.Columns[0].AddAttribute(r1, "text", 0);
        MyTree.Columns[1].AddAttribute(r2, "text", 1);
        MyTree.Columns[2].AddAttribute(r3, "text", 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the [has-entry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererCombo.html#GtkCellRendererCombo--has-entry) property to `False`.

This will result in something like (I'm not good at C#):

```
var r3 = new Gtk.CellRendererCombo();
r3.SetHasEntry(false); // or if that fails, use
r3.SetProperty('has-entry', false);
```